# "notifyAll()" in java threads: unexpected waiting time

Tags: java

I am reading some code in OCA/OCP Java SE 7 Programmer I & II Study Guide, and I got stuck on an example:

```
package threads;
class Totalizer implements Runnable
{
    int total = 0;
    public void run(){
        synchronized(this){
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                total += i;     
            }
            notifyAll();
        }   
    }   
}
class Tester extends Thread
{
    Totalizer t;
    public Tester(Totalizer tot){t = tot;}
    public void run(){
        synchronized(t){
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for calculation...");
                t.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println(t.total);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Totalizer t = new Totalizer();
        new Tester(t).start();
        new Tester(t).start();
        new Tester(t).start();
    }
}
//
```

When I run main(), it prints:

```
waiting for calculation...
waiting for calculation...
waiting for calculation...
```

and nothing happens, no calculation, nothing. I can't figure out what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Problem is that you call `notifyAll()` before the other threads have called `wait()`, thus no thread is notified when you call `notifyAll()`.

Comment: I see you started `Tester` thread but I dont see call to start Thread `Totalizer`

Comment: As an aside: you could flag the whole method `public synchronized void run() {` since this implicitly synchronizes the whole `run()`-method on `this`.

Comment: Thanks. the threads are waiting for the calculation in Totalizer. so the notifyAll() should go there, shouldn't it?

Comment: @1m9K this seems like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are you trying to achieve? Oh and you may want to add `join()`-Statements at the end of your main to wait for thread completion.

Comment: @Dhananjay: That was my first guess. the constructor: Thread(Runnable r) should normally starts the runnable. thus no need to start it. am i right?

Comment: @1m9K "*the constructor: Thread(Runnable r) should normally starts the runnable*" - No, you need to start the threads by calling `.start()` (as you do in your sample code).

Comment: @Turing85: the code shows what i want to achieve. the threads are waiting for the Totalizer to make the computation. Thread(Runnable r) will call the run() method of runnable. but won't start it. should start somewhere to make it runnable and make the threads aware of its state.

Comment: @1m9K Your code shows a deadlocking program, which is obviously not what you want to achieve. Remove the `notifyAll()` from `Totalizer::run()`, move the `System.out.println(...)` from `Tester::run` before the `synchronized`-block and remove the `t.wait()`. I think this should you give the result you want.

Comment: Oh and you need a `Totalizer`-thread: `Thread t0 = new Thread(t); t0.start();`

Comment: You are creating 3 instances of `Tester` but only one instance of `Totalizer`. Since you are using `synchronized(t)` only 1 `Totalizer` will run at a time. They will not run concurrently which negates the need for threading and could be causing your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points.

The most obvious one is that you never start the `Totalizer` runnable, so the notifyAll call is never issued. You need to have a line

```
new Thread(t).start();
```

somewhere in your `main` method. But even if you do that, it won't work reliably, as the `wait` call may be invoked *after* the `notifyAll` call. It may also print the output too early, as the `wait` call can wake up without a `notifyAll` as well.

The [Javadoc for `Object.wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) describes what you need to do:

```
synchronized (obj) {
    while (<condition does not hold>)
        obj.wait();
    ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
}
```

So, you can't just call Object.wait just like that, if you want to use it correctly. This is because:

- You don't know if the condition was already satisfied earlier, before you started waiting
- The wait call may also wake up without a notify call

In your case, you need a condition variable that you can check. For example, you can change your code like this:

```
class Totalizer implements Runnable
{
    int total = 0;
    boolean calculationComplete; // Condition to check in wait()
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            total += i;     
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            // Indicate condition for wait() is now true
            calculationComplete = true;
            notifyAll();
        }   
    }   
}
class Tester extends Thread
{
    Totalizer t;
    public Tester(Totalizer tot){t = tot;}
    public void run(){
        synchronized(t) {
            System.out.println("Waiting for calculation...");
            // Loop, terminate when condition is true
            while (!t.calculationComplete) {
                try {
                    t.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }

            System.out.println(t.total);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Erwin. i tested it. it's cleaner and did the job. much to find when looking for best.

Comment: Shouldn't `calculationComplete` declared as `volatile` to disable caching or does the `synchronized`-block take care of this?

Comment: @Turing85 the `synchronized` already takes care of that. From JLS 17.4.5 [An unlock on a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock on that monitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) (and for `volatile`: A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field.) There is no need for `volatile` if you properly synchronize - `volatile` is more like a light-weight version of `synchronized` without the monitor-locking effects.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt you are most probably right since [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) does not set the fields `volatile` either, but the cited parts of the JLS talk about two different things. The `synchronized` talks about happens-before w.r.t. the lock/unlock of the monitor, while the `volatile` talks about the happens-before w.r.t. reads/writes of field values.

Comment: @Turing85 there is only one happens-before relationship, not two separate ones. All actions that happen-before b (as in the JLS definitions of "happens-before") are visible by b. ("If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second." as the JLS explains it). So both points, and the 3 points below it, talk about the same "happens-before".

Comment: @Turing85 synchronized creates a hb relationship between an unlock and a subsequent lock. In the code, if `calculationComplete = true` is executed, then any subsequent read within a `synchronized(t)` block is guaranteed to see the new value (because another synchronized block can only be executed after an unlock/lock action).

Comment: Another excerpt burried in a lot of verbiage : "When you use wait() and notify() or notifyAll() , you should ALMOST ALWAYS also have a while loop around the wait() that checks a condition and forces continued waiting until the condition is met". @ErwinBolwidt you make it clear crystal.

Comment: @assylias "*because another synchronized block can only be executed after an unlock/lock action*" - that is the part I am struggling with. The happens-before order on the monitor-lock/-unlock is clear. But if the second thread could have the value of `computationComplete`-field cached, it is not forced to fetch the (updated) value from main memory and thus it is not guaranteed to see the new value. At least, I do not see it specified in the JLS.

Comment: @Turing85 but the value can't be changed while thread 2 is holding the lock so there is no problem even if a cached value is used. When thread 2 releases the lock, thread 1 may change the value of the field (while holding the lock). When thread 2 reacquires the lock (which can only happen after thread 1 has released it) it will see the latest value bc of the hb relationship.